# time seen from inside function surprisingly lower than time seen from calling code

Tags: c#, performance, function-calls

I have a problem with time measuring that's really bothering me. I am executing something like the following code (in C#) :

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
Foo(args);
sw.Stop();
//log time

public void Foo(var args)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    //do stuff
    sw.Stop();
    //log time
}
```

And the result is a big difference between both times, my code gives me : 15535 ms from inside the function, and 15668 ms from the outside... 133ms seems a lot to me for a function call (even with the 10 params I am giving to mine), or to incriminate Stopwatch precision (which is supposed to be super precise).

How would you explain this difference in times ?

*note 1* : Same thing happens on several successive calls : I am getting 133, 81, 72, 75, 75 milliseconds difference for 5 calls

*note 2* : the actual parameters of my function are :

- 6 class objects
- one array of struct (the array is passed as reference, right ?)
- 2 ref int
- 1 out byte[]
- 1 out class
- 1 out struct of small size (< 25 bytes)

*Update* :
In Release, the difference for the first call is even bigger (is JIT compilation more expensive in release, which could explain that ?), and the next steps have the same overhead (~75 ms)
I tried to initialize stopwatches outside, pass one as parameter and log outside of the function, the difference is still there.

I also forgot that I am giving some properties as parameters that have to be constructed the first time, so the 50ms difference for the first call might be explained by properties initialization and JIT compilation.

Comment: Possibly JIT, since `Foo()` will be Jitted the first time it's hit, so the stopwatch from outside will include that time, whereas the internal timing will not.

Comment: Try out running it 100 times and collect results in a list, then post here. perhaps GC collect occured...

Comment: @Zonko What are the arguments to `Foo()`? Are any of them particularly large `struct`s?

Comment: Are you running these tests in debug mode or release mode? Are you running with the debugger attached? To get accurate timings, you have to run in release mode without the debugger attached. That is, compile in Release mode and run from the command line or in the IDE by selecting "Run without debugging" (Ctrl+F5).

Comment: What type of logging are you doing?  What happens if you create the Stopwatch that you use inside the function so that it lives outside the function and then do the logging after both Stopwatches are done to eliminate the time involved in the logging?

Comment: I edited my question to add details.
the code is executed in debug mode without debugger attached. I'll eventually try a release run when I have time.

Comment: The time required to create another Stopwatch, Start() and Stop() it, and do whatever your logging involves is included in the time being measured by the outer Stopwatch. Have you instrumented how much of the difference in runtimes is due to this logging overhead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, It was a property calling a property doing some disk read access. I thought it was a simple member and didn't go deep enough. I took the calls out of the function call and times are now almost the same (0-1 ms, I guess it's the logging)

The moral is : properties should not have side effects. If you make a property that is not doing something obvious, code a function instead, or at least warn the next developer about what you are doing in the documentation of the property !

And the moral of the moral is : If something looks suspicious, always look at the call tree to the deepest level !